# Shade smooth not working on specific project

Tags: shaders

I'm a newbie in **Blender** and probably this's a question asked dozen of times but answers found around will not apply to my problem ... I'm trying to enable smooth shading for the mesh in this project and I'm unable to do so.
The original mesh was imported from a `.glb` file I did not mess around with materials or other properties.
This's the mesh as it appear after enabling `shade smooth`.

[image: shade smooth fails]

I have some other meshes imported from different formats (`.ac3d`) where I can change between smooth and flat without any problem:

[image: shade smooth working]

Comment: Hello, if the object is subdivided a lot, it may not look smooth if the edges tend to flatten some parts, please show the topology

Comment: can you provide your blend file so we can check it out?

Comment: @Chris sure ... you can find it [here](https://github.com/weirdgyn/Folgore), the filename is `mc202.blend`.

Comment: @moonboots it's not subdivided much more than other mesh I show below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your topology. It is really messy.

There are lots of double vertices.

You can improve it a bit by doing this:

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter edit mode. Select vertex mode.

[image]

Press <kbd>M</kbd> -> by distance ->

[image]

with these values it gets better...but...honestly, your model needs retopology!

Result (a bit better but far from perfect):

[image]

Comment: beautiful! (it worked).... thnx.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

All your faces are separate so Blender can't smooth between them, select all and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*.